# Python pandas select top 2 from each column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.8

I have a giant dataframe as:

```
Na  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
A    77      42      88     
B    31              64     
C    86      79      79      99 
D            94      8       95 
E    95      40      27     
F    92      71      32
```

I want to select the top 2 from each column to create the following:

```
Na  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
A                   88  
C           79      79      99 
D           94              95
E    95             
F    92
```

I am not sure how to approach this other than to loop through each column of dataframe and outer join them but my original dataframe is very large.

Comment: Why `col3` is `88` and `79`? And not both `88`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can just use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) in every column, setting `n=2` to retrieve the top 2 items.

```
df.set_index('Na').apply(pd.Series.nlargest, n=2)
```

---

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
A   NaN   NaN  88.0   NaN
C   NaN  79.0   NaN  99.0
D   NaN  94.0  88.0  95.0
E  95.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
F  92.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
```